# Java Parameter Generic interface

Tags: java, generics

I have a problem with parameter generic interfaces. I have 2 different interfaces and I need to pass the interface to a constructor, but  the constructor gives a warning.

```
public interface FormFragmentContract {
  interface View extends BaseView {
    void updateWorkshopUI(int icon);
    void showRemoveFavoriteDialog(String wsId, String name);
    void favoriteOnClick();
    void showSnackbar();
  }
}

public interface WorkshopListContract {
  interface View extends BaseView {
    void initializeMap();
    void onSuccessInitMap();

    void favoriteOnClick();
    void showSnackBar(String message);
   }
}
```

and the constructor code `this` gives warning like below:

```
 workshopAdapter = new WorkshopAdapter(mActivity, workshopList, this); <- this give warning mismatch type

 public WorkshopAdapter(Context context, List<Workshop> workshops, //NEED TO BE GENERIC) {
    this.context = context;
    this.workshops = workshops;
}
```

How to make both of my interface generic so it can take both interfaces as parameter ?

EDIT : because both interface contain favoriteOnClick() , If I pass the `FormFragmentContract` into the constructor I can use the favoriteOnClick() from `FormFragment` and vice versa with `WorkshopListContract` if I pass that to the constructor as well.

Comment: So do I understand you correctly, you either want `FormFragmentContract` **OR** `WorkshopListContract` to be able to put into the constructor?

Comment: @Lino see edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a separate interface with the common methods:

Something like:

```
public interface WorkshopContractView extends BaseView {
    void favoriteOnClick();
    void showSnackBar(String message);
}
```

Then make both interfaces extend it:

```
public interface FormFragmentContract extends WorkshopContractView  {
    void updateWorkshopUI(int icon);
    void showRemoveFavoriteDialog(String wsId, String name);
}

public interface WorkshopListContract extends WorkshopContractView {
    void initializeMap();
    void onSuccessInitMap();
}
```

Not sure why you had nested interfaces there. They seemed redundant.

Then just have your generic constructor accept the `WorkshopContractView` like this:

```
public WorkshopAdapter(Context context, List<Workshop> workshops, WorkshopContractView view) {
    this.context = context;
    this.workshops = workshops;
//...
}
```

Comment: because FormFragmentContract also contains another interface for Presenter  but i didnt post it. Thank you for answer and i also tried this way and it worked however i want to do the generic way. Can you help ?

Comment: So why not have `FormFragmentContract extends Presenter, BaseView` ?

Comment: it just that from the start the architecture is already like that they prefer separate it rather than extend